# routerLink doesn't navigate to lazy loading modules for a named router outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I am trying to navigate to the component defined in a lazy loading module using the named `router-outlet`. When I click on the Test button (*test.component.html*) I get the exception:

> NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'.

My *app-routing.module.ts* is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.gard';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


const myModule = () => import('./my-routing/my-routing.module').then(x => x.MyRoutingModule);
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'experiment', loadChildren: myModule },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent, outlet: "outlet1"
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My *test.component.html* looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['home'] }}]" routerLinkActive="active"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Home</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ outlet1: ['experiment','test'] }}]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Test</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My *my-routing.module.ts* looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from '../list.component';
import { TestComponent } from '../test/test.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'test', component: ListComponent, outlet: "outlet1" },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `[routerLink]` as below for the [auxiliary route](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/).

```
<a [routerLink]="['experiment', { outlets:{ outlet1: ['test'] }}]">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Test
    </button>
</a>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xsm4ek?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts)

Comment: Note that, I am not so familiar with the auxiliary route. So I write it as a comment here. Based on my understanding, Your outlet: "outlet1"` is applied to the child route ("test") but not to the parent ("experiment"). Thus, your auxiliary route should be with "test" only. Welcome anyone to provide further elaborate on it. Thanks.

Comment: When you click on `Test` button the whole screen is wiped out and `List` word appears. Why the screen is wiped out ?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, if you compare both `AppRoutingModule` and `MyRoutingModule`, there is a base component with route: '' in `AppRoutingModule` but `MyRoutingModule` doesn't have. There is no base component to be displayed in `<router-outlet>` when redirecting to "experiment". You can try forking the repository, add the base path: `{ path: '', component: /* Your component */ }` in the `MyRoutingModule`. This will display the base component in `<router-outlet>` .

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand. Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: What is base component?

Comment: Mean you need to assign a component with path '' in the `MyRoutingModule`. Have you tried forking the repository, add the code, and see the result?

Comment: I have added into `MyRoutingModule` the `{ path: '', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'test', component: ListComponent , outlet: "outlet2"}` but still does not work

Comment: Hi @janci, what is not working? Check my latest demo. And there is no `<router-outlet>` with name: "outlet2" as in your question. So why do you specify the route with `outlet: "outlet2"` rather than "outlet1"?

Comment: Hi Yong Shun. Sorry about outlet2 - I was just experimenting. Back to your Demo. When you press in your demo button `Home` both buttons remain on the screen, but when you press `Test` button both buttons disappear - how do I make them remain on the screen.

Comment: Back to the third comment of the answer, as you didn't provide the route '' in your `MyRoutingModule`, thus the default `<router-outlet>` will not show anything. If you check back my demo, now it will show both "List", as I added the default route (route: '' with ListComponent).

Comment: Pressing `Home` button leaves the buttons (`Home` and `Test`) on the screen and displays `Home` (at the bottom). In the same way I would like to press the `Test` button and have the buttons (`Home` and `Test`) stay on the screen like as if we pressed `Home` button and display `List` at the bottom/top. Can that be done?

Comment: 1. As I said either you need to specify the base path of your routing module to display the base component that you want. Or in your root component, you can render the component that needs to be displayed in every page.